# How can I run a JavaScript file in bash

Tags: javascript, bash

I want to run a javaScript file in bash for example,
 I can use python like this ->

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
print("Hello World!")
```

How can I do similar with javaScript?

```
#!/usr/bin/env js
```

Besides, which interpreter should I use, nodejs?

Comment: 1) the `bash` file you mention is not a bash file, it's a *python* file.  2) node will be easiest to run JavaScript from the command line

Comment: Posting on stackoverflow should be done *after* you've googled this, not before.

Comment: I figured it out, #!/usr/bin/jjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, we don't have to call node. We can call the

```
#!/usr/bin/jjs
```

directly on the bash file, I works like magic